# Which Java collection classes are better to use in multi-thread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Hi I am new for working on Java multi thread environment.  I have to add,update and remove the set of objects in collection at one thread. And at this same time I going to check and iterate the object at another thread.

List and set are not thread safe. Can any one please share me that which one of the collection/Map classes are better to use on multi thread environment ?

Comment: provide more details about the type of collection.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html ... I mean, you even *tagged* this question with the answer (Who upvotes this?).

Comment: The single threaded collections are still better to use if you can ensure that only one threaded will every access that collection.  The answer is; it depends.  ConcurrentHashMap is great but is much larger and a bit slower than HashMap, only use it if you need to.

Answer (score 6):

Yes,

There s [`ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)  in java, you can use it.

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.

More over `Collections`  utility class have methods to synchronize.

```
Collections.synchronizedCollection(YourCollection);
```

And other methods like

[`synchronizedList(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

[`synchronizedSet(Set<T> s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29)

Comment: Hi suresh, 
In my case i don't need to use key and pair values.

Comment: @Murali Yes Murali. Edited my post.

Comment: Even if you use synchronizedSet(Set<T> s) or synchronizedList(List<T> list) , please make sure you synchronized the return set.Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)

Answer (score 1):

May be vector in case you dont want to save key-value or "Collections.synchronizedList().

Answer (score 1):

You could use a concurrent hash set created from the `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
 Set<K> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<K, Object>());
```

This collection is thread-safe and has the features of the `ConcurrentHashMap` - it's faster than `Collections.synchronized*` wrappers.

Be aware though that thread safety for a collection doesn't guarantee thread-safety for it's items. In order to achieve the least a common possible approach is to make the items read-only: i.e. immutable or returning copies on access.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections API

```
public static <T> Set<T> synchronizedSet(Set<T> s)
```

*Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) set backed by the specified set*

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list)
```

*Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list*

You can pass your List or Set implementation to the above methods and get a thread-safe one

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, it has several thread safe collections

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) and [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html).
Read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) as well.